# Python - Device Model with different operating modes

Tags: python, oop, model, state

I am interested in modelling a device in Python. Let us take a camera for example with two different operating modes, i. e. photo mode and video mode. In general methods from the photo mode should not be callable when the video mode is active and vice versa. I. e. one should not be able to change the framerate (fps) from the video mode within the photo mode.

One idea to implement this device with restricted access to other modes is to create a controller class which manages the communication between components within the camera (open/close serial ports, perform hardware tests etc.). Within the controller class the implemented modes (photo mode and video mode) could be assigned to the controller while the modes could be implemented as own classes/libraries.

A valid command set could be:

```
# Python 3
CameraController = Controller()  # Creates an instance of the controller class 'Controller'
CameraController.open()  # Opens all communication ports and other things
CameraController.PhotoMode.open()  # Opens/Initializes the photo mode
CameraController.PhotoMode.take_picture()  # Command of photo mode to take a picture

# It would be necessary to close the actual mode and to initialize the alternative mode

CameraController.VideoMode.open()  # Should give a warning/error/closes automatically the PhotoMode
CameraController.VideoMode.take_video()  #  Command of video mode to take a video
```

This behaviour could be reached by manipulating the `__getattribute__(self, *args, **kwargs)` method of the built-in object class in Python and to check (before methods or properties are evaluated) if the requested mode is active or not.

Does anybody know a different approach for modelling the stated behaviour? I made some research on the internet but did not find a better solution for this kind of problem. I would like to learn how to implement this behaviour in the most common way. Also other common approaches from other programming languages are welcome since code portability is sometimes important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__getattr__` to achieve this.

```
class Controller(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = None

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in ['PhotoMode', 'VideoMode']:
            self.mode = item
        return self

    def open(self):
        if self.mode is None:
            # code to open all ports
            print("opened all ports")
        elif self.mode == 'PhotoMode':
            # open photo ports / close other ports based on self.mode
            print("photo mode opened")
        elif self.mode == 'VideoMode':
            # open video modes / close other ports based on self.mode
            print("video mode opened")
        else:
            #error
            print("unknown mode")

    def take_picture(self):
        if self.mode != 'PhotoMode':
            #error
            print("wrong mode for photo")
        # take picture
        pass

    def take_video(self):
        if self.mode != 'VideoMode':
            #error
            print("wrong mode for video")
        # take picture
        pass



# Python 3
CameraController = Controller()  # Creates an instance of the controller class 'Controller'
CameraController.open()  # Opens all communication ports and other things
CameraController.PhotoMode.open()  # Opens/Initializes the photo mode
CameraController.PhotoMode.take_picture()  # Command of photo mode to take a picture

# It would be necessary to close the actual mode and to initialize the alternative mode

CameraController.VideoMode.open()  # Should give a warning/error/closes automatically the PhotoMode
CameraController.VideoMode.take_video()  #  Command of video mode to take a video
```

Comment: The suggested solution is interesting. There are some things that I would like to avoid:

- The different modes are not implemented as classes (strings are used to differentiate between them) and therefore code maintenance is more difficult

- Every command must use if-else clauses explicitly to check if the respective method can be executed

Is there a more sophisticated strategy for the problem?